# Numbers of vowel won't come out in the output

Tags: c++

I'm having problems with how to show the numbers of vowels in the string I input in this code I made

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   char str[100];
   int a, e, i, o, u, whitespace;
   a = e = i = o = u = whitespace = 0;
   int k;

   cout << "Enter a string: ";
   cin >> str[99];
        
   for (k = 0; k < strlen(str); k++)
   {
       if (str[k] == 'A')
       {
           a = a + 1;
       }
       else if (str[k] == 'E')
       {
           e = e + 1;
       }
       else if (str[k] == 'I')
       {
           i = i + 1;
       }
       else if (str[k] == 'O')
       {
           o = o + 1;
       }
       else if (str[k] == 'U')
       {
           u = u + 1;
       }
       else if (str[k] == ' ')
       {
           whitespace++;
       }
   }

   cout << "\nVowels:\n";
   cout << "A " << a;
   cout << "\nE " << e;
   cout << "\nI " << i;
   cout << "\nO " << o;
   cout << "\nU " << u;
   cout << "\nWhitespaces - " << whitespace;

    return 0;
}
```

I hope I just need to tweak a few things because I'm new to programming lol

I typed "WELCOME TO ARRAYS" but the vowels and whitespace shows 0

Comment: The `cin >> str[99];` is wrong as it reads in only one character into the arrays last element. Try `cin >> str;`.

Comment: `cin >> str[99];` reads 1 `char` and stores it in 99th position in your array; the rest of your array is uninitialized garbage.

Comment: Consider using `std::string str;` instead of a "C" style fixed size character array. And use str.size() to get its length.

Comment: Consider using `switch/case` statement instead of an `if-else-if` ladder.  Also consider using a string search (have a string of vowels and search it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here

```
cin >> str[99];
```

You must write to the beginning of the array so just pass

```
cin >> str;
```

or if you want to be more clear pass the address of the first element

```
cin >> &str[0];
```

and str will be filled from the beginning ith the chars you enter.

The >> operator only reads until the first whitespace though, so it would only count vowels of the first word.

So in general cin.getline or std::getline is better as it reads everything

```
cin.getline(str,sizeof(str));
```

Comment: since C++20 `operator>>` has an overload for c string (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).  Then `cin >> &str[0];` is not just about readability/clarity but its less safe

Comment: (acutally I though it exists before C++20 already, but I might remember wrong and cannot find it)